# Port 80 shows already in use while no process is running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, localhost

I need to run my ruby on rails application with my custom domain name.

I have already replaced 'localhost' with 'rails' so that i could run the app as  "rails:3000".
Now, I need to remove the port number(3000) as well.

When i try to run ,

rvmsudo rails server -p 80

the error that the port is already in use occurs,but there is no process running in the port-80

Comment: Was there a process using that port that you killed instead of letting it shut down gracefully?

Comment: A process was using it which i killed using kill -9 PID command

Comment: Thought so. Look into `SO_REUSEADDR`.

Comment: Don't put tags like "linux-kernel" to completely unrelated topics.

Answer (score 0):

It must be used by another process. I suggest use below command to see which process is using 80 port.

ps -nap | grep 80

Comment: The above listed command and the command : lsof -wni tcp:80 , both results nothing